# My cookie gets reset after clicking button

Tags: jquery, cookies, joomla

I have a joomla site and I am using rsform component to create a multi-page form. I am saving all the input field values in a cookie before the form is submitted just in case the user decides they can't finish filling out the form. So if the user returns I have a function which will take the cookie and loop through the form and populate the form fields with values which are stored in the cookie. I can create and read the cookie but I can't repopulate the form. Here is the flow.

1. User goes to website and website checks if they have a cookie stored on machine if not it gets created.
2. The cookie gets populated when the user clicks the button to go to the next form view which at that time I take the form and I create a json stringify serialized array from it and pass it to the cookie to be stored.

But I noticed that the cookie does not get populated with the values until I am about three form views deep. For example if I fill in the first two textareas and click the next button to get to the next form view, in the console I see the cookie key pairs but the values are empty. But if I fill in the next textarea and click the next button I can see the value for the first two textareas in the console but not for the textarea I just filled out. I hope I you guys can understand what I am trying to say. I have been at this for weeks and I can't figure it out so any help is much appreciated. Here is a link to the form http://hearwithyourheartusa.com/index.php/share-your-story. It maybe easier to see what I am trying to say rather than trying to understand what I just typed out.

**EDIT**
Here is the code I am using to set and get the cookie and the code which should populate the form with the values of the ccokie. I also have a jsfiddle but it refuses to set the cookie but here is the link if you want to give it a shot http://jsfiddle.net/Uqj4x/

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)===' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function string2form($form, serializedStr) {
    var fields = JSON.parse(serializedStr);
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var controlName = fields[i].name;
        var controlValue = fields[i].value;     
        $form.find("[name='+ controlName +']").attr('value',controlValue);
        //document.getElementsByName(controlName).value = controlValue;
        //console.log('field name='+controlName+' field value='+controlValue);
    }
        console.log('form values are - '+JSON.stringify(jQuery('#userForm').serializeArray()));
        var cookie = readCookie('storyCookie');
        console.log('the cookie values are '+cookie);
}
      jQuery('#userForm input:button').click(function() {
    // jQuery.ajax({
        // cache: false,
        // type: 'POST',
        // url: 'http://hearwithyourheartusa.com/templates/jsn_boot_pro/customPHP/ajaxcookie.php',
        // data: JSON.stringify(jQuery('#userForm').serializeArray()),
        // contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        // dataType: 'json',
        // success: function(data){
            // alert(data);
        // }
    // });
    console.log(id);
    createCookie('storyCookie',JSON.stringify(jQuery('#userForm').serializeArray()),365);
    var cookie = readCookie('storyCookie');
    console.log('the cookie is '+cookie);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried filling in the form but it's not setting any cookies. Also I couldn't find the code that saves the cookies (it should be in rsfp_changePage, right?)

Anyhow, did you set the cookie expiration time in the future?

Comment: Yea sorry I removed the code to set the cookie via JQuery and create an Ajax request which sends the cookie to a PHP script which actually send the data as soon as the button is clicked and the cookie will be created with PHP. So the code is now in an external file called custom_form.js. Should've mentioned this earlier but I was up late last night working on it.

Comment: works fine now... as soon as I set a description and press "next" the cookie is set. What is strange however is that you used ids with spaces in them, I know it works but it's asking for trouble...

Comment: There is a big issue with the cookie you're setting, it expires in the past (i.e. the moment the button is pressed it seems), you should set an expiration date in the future.

Comment: Yea the Ids are set through the rsform component I might have to go back and change that to make sure it doesn't mess me up later. As for the cookie expiration I set it like this date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();                                                                 Cookie gets created but I cant loop through form to prepopulate my form fields with the values of the cookie. So when the page is loaded the form is empty so when you click the button it recreates the cookie again with no field values

Comment: maybe you're trying to access the form before it's created and available? try to include your call in a document ready or even quicker for testing, just set a timeout to 2 seconds and see if it works...